# kendoAutoComplete for multiple dataTextField

Tags: php, codeigniter, kendo-ui

The code below works for autocomplete for FileNo (field) only. i want this function to work for other attributes of employee too. i.e FirstName, LastName

dataTextField: "FileNo" <---------------- here dataTextField gets sing field. how could it be for multiple fields?
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are the one that knows on which columns want to search, my recommendation is:

1. Implement `index.php/hr_management/manage_hr/search_employee/` in such way that is able to do the search for any of the columns that you want (`FileNo`, `FirstName`, `LastName`...).
2. This service will return three columns (at least) providing an `id`, *column name* on which you found the match and *match value*.
3. *match value* is used for displaying values in the `autocomplete`.
4. Once selected value on `autocomplete` use the *column name* and *match value* for filtering on the `grid`.

Answer (score 2):

You should use **template** to change what is displayed in the dropdownlist of the autocomplete. Then the dataTextField will only be used inside the input element.

[Here](http://demos.kendoui.com/web/autocomplete/template.html) is how it goes to create template.

Comment: Thanks i tried it. it was also good but it returns the template or other details from table when i type FileNo. What i want is to search the same record with for instance FirstName too.

Comment: The template is only for styling the items of dropdownlist. The problem is as to how you fetch items in combination of fields rather than being restricted to single field set to dataTextField.  See my answer above.

Answer (score 2):

Kendo Autocomplete has dataTextField that accepts a field name(e.g. employeeID, employeeName etc. of a datasource ) to use for filtering items.

To use multiple fields, you have to set one of the fields to hold **concatenated fields** during *parsing* of datasource in your **schema** as given below.
Then set your **filter** of AutoComplete to "**contains**"

I did it as follows.

```
var myDataSrc = new kendo.data.DataSource({    
                    transport: {
                        read: {
                            type:"GET",
                            url:clientDataURL,
                            dataType: "jsonp",
                            contentType: "application/json",
                        }                           
                    }, 
                      schema: {
                            parse: function(clntDB) {
                                $.each(clntDB, function(ky, clnt) {
                                  clnt.firstName = clnt.clientUID + " | " + clnt.firstName+ "  " + clnt.lastName;

                                });
                                return clntDB;
                            } 
                     },
                     pageSize: 4    // Number of Items to show during input
        });
```

///  See the **firstName** above it's reconstructed to hold concatenated lastname , ID and firstname string.

Next step is to use parsed firstName  as a value of **dataTextField** of kendo Autocomplete.

Then
var selectedClntID; //// Actually, this aims at getting the ID for future use

```
$("#YOURSEARCHINPUTID").kendoAutoComplete({
                dataSource: myDataSrc ,
                template:   tmplSrchdClnt,  // YOUR TEMPLATE like "<div>firstName</div>"            
                dataTextField:"firstName",  
                filter:"contains",    /// DON'T FORGET TO ADD THIS
                minLength    : 1 ,
                select: function(e) {
                   var selectedClnt = this.dataItem(e.item.index()),
                       x = kendo.stringify(selectedClnt);
                       selectedClntID =    JSON.parse(x);


               }
                // headerTemplate: '<div><h2>ID - LastName</h2></div>'
        });
```

However, tough to find resource indicating like this, it's awesome when you see it working.This is engine of my project when it comes to autocompletion. I did it this way.

Alternatively, you can convert to

**data** = new Employee(firstname, lastname, ID);  // on client side

```
function Employee( firstname, lastname, ID ){
  this.filterStr = firstname + ""+lastname+" "+ID;
}
```

give **data** to kendo AutoComplete dataSource and use **filterStr** as dataTextField.

Comment: By Far the best solution, so easy to implement too, thanks!

Comment: @user25794 you're very welcome. I'm glad it works for you as well.

Answer (score 0):

Another code example adding a new field to the datacourse to use as dataTextField.

```
// Build our data source object.
var dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
  transport: {
    read: {
      url: readUrl,
    }
  },
  group: {field: "region"},
  schema: {
    data: function(response) {
      $.each(response, function(k, v) {
        response[k].searchString = v.airport + " " + v.iataCode;
      });

      return response;
    }
  }
});


$(selector).kendoAutoComplete({
  dataTextField: "searchString",
  filter: "contains",
  template: '<span class="k-state-default">#: data.airport # (#: data.iataCode #)</span>',
  height: 400,
  dataSource: dataSource,
});
```